# Iframe scrolling overflow hidden not working in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

Here is the iframe

```
<iframe class="iframe_style" id="iframeid" src="#" height="100%" width="100%" ></iframe>
```

I'm using CSS as overflow: hidden, but still I'm getting scrolling..

```
.iframe_style{
border: 3px solid red;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dineshmsp/Lxjy4ae6/)

Any help on this?

Answer (score 2):

As I can see in your fiddle you set iframe `overflow` to `hidden` which will work for Iframe contents

If you want to make it for `body`, just add

```
body{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lxjy4ae6/46/)**

Comment: Your Post was for overflow not for borders...bro :)

Comment: can you please fix it for borders too?

Comment: ok I need to know that if the height of iframe goe beyond the height of window the border will cut..what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: block` to the iframe.

```
.iframe_style{
    border: 3px solid red;
    display: block;
}
```

Don't forget to account for the border that you have added. Subtract the border size from the width and height using jQuery.

```
var window_height = $(window).height() - 6;
var window_width = $(window).width() - 6;
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Lxjy4ae6/50/

Answer (score 0):

```
body, html { 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Should do the trick.